# Is ngx_http_upstream_module comes built-in with Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I compile nginx without specifying `--with-http_upstream_module` and it's not listed in the `nginx -V` output but I still can use `upstream` directive in my configs. Is upstream module prebuilt in nginx core? How can I learn which modules like this also built-in?

Comment: The [documentation](nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) will state if a module is not built by default. Also, look at the source code, particularly the `auto/options` file which appears to specify the modules that are built by default.